# Difference between mingw/lib vs msys/1.0/lib?

Tags: mingw, msys

I am setting up a mingw/msys (mingw.org) environment in which to compile some old code that uses this approach to produce some Windows programs. These link to libraries such as libgdi32.a and libz.a etc.

I notice that the combined mingw/msys environment contains two lib folders, and each contains a version of these files, which are different. The files in the msys directory are generally larger and older, it seems.

**So my question is: what's the significance of the two lib folders, and why the two versions of the same files?**

Further background detailing the mingw setup I have, which I believe to be pretty vanilla:

I downloaded MinGW (mingw-get-setup.exe) from here: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started and followed what I believe to be a pretty standard installation.

During that installation I selected (in MinGW installation manager) to include msys, and several libraries that I expect to need. (So I did not perform a separate install for msys.) I can run msys.bat to open an msys window, and can compile a project using make (and a Makefile).

With this vanilla setup, we get C:\MinGW, including C:\MinGW\lib, and C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\ with various subdirs including C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\lib.

And from within msys console, these library folders are at /lib and /mingw/lib (ie: msys sets up a mount point so that mingw appears within msys's root.)

Example libraries that appear in both libs:

```
File              mingw               msys
libz.a            4/21/2018 126k     5/13/2012 343k
libgdi32.a        7/8/2020  221k     1/14/2010 252k
libwinspool.a     7/8/2020   86k     1/14/2010  98k
libws2_32.a       7/8/2020  109k     1/14/2010  82k
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSYS is the stuff to make the Unix shell commands work. Similar to Cygwin it contains a compatibility/emulation layer.
MinGW is Ffor native Windows programs.
You should only include and link with MinGW folders for your Windows projects.

If you don't use the Unix shell (bash) then you don't even need MSYS and you can even use a standalone MinGW-w64 build like http://winlibs.com

Comment: Thanks for answering, but... OK, I know the idea is that msys provides a unix-like shell, which I am using to run configure scripts, make, gcc etc. But sticking with your comment that "SYS is the stuff to make the Unix shell commands work", what does msys/1.0/lib/  do, given that it contains a bunch of lib<name>.a files, which are presumably only good for linking with statically? How do those help shell commands work?

Comment: MSYS libraries are for building those shell commands from source. Don't link with those unless you know exactly what you are doing. Stick with the MinGW libraries for your projects.

Comment: OK! That makes sense. Thanks